# AppIcon will showed twice on device with Android App

Tags: android

When i install my android application on the device, the AppIcon will appear twice.

This means: there are two separate app-icons. Both icons launch the same app version. If I remove one app-icon, the other disappears also. If i reinstall them, it appears twice again.

How can i avoid this?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.******"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
             android:value="524b0194108e90ae383189e509746766"/>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You only have one launcher activity... If you uninstall one, does the other go away?

Comment: Do you have both `debug` and `release` builds installed? Sometimes we set those up with separate `applicationId` values, so you can have your next version on the same device at the same time as your production version.

Comment: @cricket_007 just updated my question with: there are two separate app-icons. Both icons launch the same app version. If I remove one app-icon, the other disappears also. If i reinstall them, it appears twice again.

Comment: the last question edit for the manifest was definitely required info :)

Comment: yes, i found out that i postet the wrong manifest :) sorry

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the intent-filter. Only one activity should have

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Any activity having this intent filter will be shown in the launcher.

Comment: would add - "Only one activity should have ... if you only want a single entry point to your app". Having multiple entry points is sometimes legit use case, e.g. a shortcut to debug settings (would be specified in your debug manifest though)

Comment: But itinance see two icons and this is because of the two same intent-filters.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I meant "Only one activity should have" could be qualified with "if you only want a single entry point to your app" to make it clear for others coming to this question that it's not an absolute rule.

Comment: Oh, now I understand your advice. ;)